# PHP Session to restrict access to file

Tags: php, session, session-variables

index.php

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);

$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['userpass']);

$sel_user = "select * from users where user_name='$username' AND user_password='$pass'";

$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

if($check_user>0) {

$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
$_SESSION['user_name']=$username;

header("location:display.php");
die();
}

else {

echo "<script>alert('Username or Password is not correct, please try again!')</script>";

}

}
```

display.php

```
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['loggedIn']) {
header("location: index.php");
die();
}
```

Hello, I'm trying to figure out why my index.php is not letting me properly login and access my display.php The password and username is right, but keeps redirecting me to index.php Any ideas why?

Comment: so where are it redirects now?

Comment: I believe my code in index.php is wrong somehow. Even though the login credentials are correct, it wont take me to display.php

Comment: Have you a password stored in clear onto DB? o_O

Comment: Yes, i didnt include the mysqli connect portion of the php code

Comment: I'd hate to be one of those guys, but never store passwords in plaintext, you will learn your lesson in the future unless you fix this now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use Cookies instead? 
In your `login.php` page instead of:

```
if($check_user>0) {

$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
$_SESSION['user_name']=$username;

header("location:display.php");
die();
}
```

Do this:

```
if($check_user>0) {
    $_SESSION['user_name']=$username;
     $Month = 86400 + time(); 
     setcookie('user', $username, $Month); 
      header("Location:display.php");
}
```

and then on your `display.php`

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_COOKIE['user']))
{
header("location:index.php");
die();
}
```

Comment: Couldnt a user disable cookies on his browser?

Comment: @ArvinFlores Yes, but that is a different side of the story. You could also change the settings in your browser for session expiry/reset.

Comment: i appreciate your help. Im fairly new to php so i didnt even know this was achievable with cookies. Im only curious though as to how come you suggested cookies? Are sessions inferior somehow?

Comment: @ArvinFlores cookies are stored on the client side and sessions on the ther hand are stored on the server. For more in-depth study have a glance here: http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/session_cookie.htm

Comment: That article definitely clarified things. Its much appreciated. Would it be too much to ask to see the above code used in a session? For my future reference

Comment: @ArvinFlores, do you mean to have a change in the above code and use sessions instead?

Comment: Precisely, if its not too much trouble. It would really help me out in the future as i plan to use cookies and sessions now that im becoming more familiar with them